# How do I include a jsp file located "above" the public_html folder

Tags: jsp, include

First, I'm from a PHP background (which may be evident by this question).  This is such a simple task to accomplish in PHP yet I'm absolutely perplexed on how to accomplish this with jsp.

This is my folder structure on the server:

```
/home +
      |
      +-/user-+
            |
            +-/includes+
            |          |
            |          +/footer.jsp
            |
            +-/public_html+
                          |
                          +/index.jsp
```

public_html is the directory being served by Apache Tomcat.  So if someone surfs to my domain (sampledomain.com)  they see index.jsp

I don't want the "footer.jsp" to be accessible directly via the web. So, it is located in the includes directory which is located one directory above "index.jsp"  There is no possible URL that you can type in a browser to reach footer.jsp directly.

Here is the content of footer.jsp

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>This is a footer</p>
</div>
```

Here is the content of index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <%@ include file="../includes/footer.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a tomcat error saying that the file "/../includes.footer.jsp" cannot be found.  How do I include a file that is outside of the web page's public_html directory.

In php, I'd just do

```
<?php include("../includes/footer.php") ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to the cause of the problem, anything outside the web content root is not part of the JSP/Servlet web application's context and should not be seen as such. You need to keep your web files inside the web content root. It's quite possible that multiple (and independent) JSP/Servlet web applications runs together in the webapp's parent folder. If whatever you tried was possible it would have been an integrity leak.

As to the functional requirement:

> *I don't want the "footer.jsp" to be accessible directly via the web.*

The `/WEB-INF` folder serves this purpose. Drop the file in there.

```
/home/user/ 
/home/user/public_html/index.jsp
/home/user/public_html/WEB-INF/includes/footer.jsp
```

And fix the `@include` accordingly:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/footer.jsp" %>
```

Last but not least, please don't compare PHP with JSP. The PHP culture is littered with many holes and poor practices. JSP actually also (as in using *scriptlets* :/), but not *that* much.

Comment: OK. I get it. But as far as poor serucity practices goes... in PHP, I would just trust Apache to prevent people from getting direct access to my footer.  It's perfectly secure. No one would be able to get to that script directly through a web browser.  It seems like JSP adds another un-necessary layer.  The WEB-INF folder reminds me of PERL's cgi-bin/ folder, which was also a pain in the butt.  It's a pre-2000's fix to a non-existent security issue.  Still, thanks. Seems like this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This /user/includes/footer.jsp should be in WebContent folder of project.

Comment: If it's in a WebContent folder, then's its accessible via the web, which is exactly what I DON'T want.  I Googled a lot of potential answers before I posted, and it seems like Java people don't understand the concept of storing files "one directory up" beyond the domain's root directory.  The solution is to store the file in the WEB-INF directory.  It's exactly the same as storing a PHP file one directory above the root--only JSP forces you to use their directory where in PHP you can pick the name of your own directory. It's just an un-necessary hoop that JSP forces you to jump through.

Answer (score 0):

had that problem, wanted to include a file that was on another directory, which was accessible through the parent, and i solved it by using this: <%@ include file="../includes/file.jsp" %>